# Is "derived" in C++ the same thing as "extended" in Java?

Tags: java, c++, inheritance, terminology

As the title states: when I "derive" a class in CPP, that's pretty much the same thing as "extending" a class in Java, yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Since Java doesn't have multiple inheritance, it can be a bit more verbose with the language. Java's `class D extends B`  is `class D : public B` in C++, but in C++ you can also have in­her­itances like `struct D : B1, private B2, protected B3`.

Similarly, in Java `super` refers to the (unique) base subobject, and understandably there is no com­par­able concept in C++ (you have to specify the base by name).

(Note that there's also `implements` in Java for dedicated *interface* classes. Since those have no mem­bers and only abstract functions, there's no need to refer to those interface bases from the derived (i.e. "implementing") class.)

Comment: OK.  Thanks for elaborating more on the Java side of things; that helps with the conceptualization.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they mean the same thing.  Although, "derived" is not a keyword in C++ the way that `extends` is in Java, even though the C++ standard uses the word "Derived" to indicate the idea of a subclass.  Inheritance in C++ is expressed using the `:` symbol, along with an optional access qualifier like `public` or `private`.

C++ inheritance is also slightly more complicated than Java inheritance, because multiple inheritance is supported, and as such virtual inheritance is also an option.

Comment: Thanks Charles, you were first but @Kerrek's answer was a little more appealing.